# Como mostrar uma imagem através do javascript?

Tags: javascript

O código a seguir está no javascript:

```
<img class=\"modal-loading\" src=\"~/Content/img/loading.gif\" />
```

O resultado final:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "no meu javascript"? Por quê a *tag* `img` estaria no seu arquivo js e não no HTML? Já tentou utilizar o caminho absoluto da imagem?

Comment: Esse código acima, não está no html, está no javascript.Porque estou usando um plugin e eu quero alterar style... Só posso alterar usando js Exemplo: `templates:{ header: "div class="" .......<img clas =....etc ../.> <button class="btn btn-success"}`

Comment: E o caminho absoluto, tentou?

Comment: Pelo caminho absoluto funciona, tem como fazer ele funcionar pelo caminho relativo ?

Comment: Tente utilizar o caminho relativo ao root da aplicação, então, não ao diretório do usuário.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

boa noite
vc ja tentou tirar o ~ do endereço ? tudo vai depender do diretorio que está a img se estiver em um sub diretorio do seu projeto web basta colocar Content/img/loading.gif

Comment: Funcionou, era só remover caractere til. `src=\"/Content/img/loading.gif\"`

Comment: Exatamente. Removendo o caractere `~`, o caminho fica relativo ao diretório raiz da aplicação.